# Unable to get dictionary attribute after filtering a list in Jinja2

Tags: templates, jinja2

I've a list of dictionaries and try to get an attribute of the last entry after a filter.
The filtering is working but don't know how to get the attribute.

The template is:

```
{% set data = [{"key1":1},{"key1":2,"key2":"value"},{"key1":3}] %}
{% if data | selectattr("key1", "equalto", 2) | list %}
elem={{ data | selectattr("key1", "equalto", 2) | list | last }}
attr={{ data | selectattr("key1", "equalto", 2) | list | last | attr("key2") }}
{% endif %}
```

The output is:

```
elem={'key1': 2, 'key2': 'value'}
attr=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround but no solution so far:

```
{% set data = [{"key1":1},{"key1":2,"key2":"value"},{"key1":3}] %}
{% for item in data | selectattr("key1", "equalto", 2) | list %}
{% if loop.last %}
elem={{ item }}
attr={{ item.key2 }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The result is now as expected:

```
elem={'key1': 2, 'key2': 'value'}
attr=value
```